# reactjs -- handle checkbox (multiple) click events

Tags: reactjs

I know there are some similar topics but none seems to be in the same direction of what I'm trying to do, thus a new thread.

I have a component that displays a list of keys, each with a checkbox attached to the string. In addition, I have a button that supposedly calls an API with all keys selected and delete these keys.

Several things I'm trying to achieve:

1. checking a check box enables the delete button
2. click the delete button should send a POST to API, the list should then reload
3. Since the list is reloaded, all checkbox should be unselected, thus the delete button is once again disabled
4. there's another button outside of this function that checks for the length of the list as well, which I don't know how to associate with this list if I fetch the list in the component.

I'm facing the problem which I don't know how to make the button and the checkboxes associate to each other. I tried using state with a `checked` state, which is a boolean, but that's only one boolean and cannot record several keys. I think using an array would work? Then again I'm not sure how to properly append or remove the key checked.

my code looks like

```
class AppList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            checked: [],
            apps: []
        };
        this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("some_url", {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({"user": "some_email"}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': ' application/json'}
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({apps: JSON.parse(result)});
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        );
    }

    handleDeleteKey = (event) => {
        // fetch(I'll worry about this later)
        this.setState({checked: false});
        console.log("delete!!!!");
    }

    handleChecked () {
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    }


    render () {
        const apps = this.state.apps.map((app) =>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChecked} />
                {`   ${app}`}
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Client Key List:</h4>
                {this.state.apps.length > 0 ? <ul>{apps}</ul> : <p>No Key</p>}
                {this.state.apps.length > 0 ? <button className="api-instruction-button" onClick={this.handleDeleteKey}>Delete Selected Key(s)</button> : null}
            </div> 
        );
    }


} 

export default AppList;
```

I feel like my design is completely wrong but I don't know how to fix it. It seems like there are so many states to be passed around and nothing is the outermost, almost a cyclic dependency.

Anyone had any experience dealing with this problem? It seems like it's a common user action but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: after digging it a bit more, it seems like I need to call `componentDidMount` outside of the `AppList`. It should be in the component that uses `AppList`, let's call it `MainApp`.

`MainApp` calls `componentDidMount` which is the same as the one in `AppList`. The one in `AppList` gets removed, and the keys are passed to AppList as props.

I have trouble handling the clicking event. It seems like the component is always updating, so if I want to append the clicked key to the array, it wouldn't work. The same call will be made again and again.

Since there's another button in `MainApp` that requires the list of keys, I can't just pass the call into `AppList`. However, updating in `AppList` should update the `MainApp` as well. How does it work? I'm so confused

EDIT2:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7w2w11477j

This recreation should contain all functions I have so far, but I can't get them to work together.

Again my task is simply:

- I have a list of strings, each with a checkbox
- checking the checkbox selects the specific string
- There's a button that I can click to delete these entries in my db by calling an API
- Is refreshing the MainApp needed in this case? Otherwise I need to delete the strings in frontend so they don't display after the delete button is pressed

Comment: I think I might be able to help, but after your most recent edit, I'm a bit confused myself. Would it be possible to duplicate your problem with both your MainApp and AppList components in an online editor such as https://codesandbox.io/ so I can take a look? That way I can visualize what trouble you're facing.

Comment: @JacobLockett I'll try to create a mimic of my app. There's some more stuff relate to company to it so I need to find a way to take them out. i'll update my post later

Comment: @JacobLockett I have attached a link: https://codesandbox.io/s/7w2w11477j

Comment: Sorry it took a little bit of time, but hopefully the code I provided helps you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I believe you were going for: https://codesandbox.io/s/w23wv002yw

The only problem that made yours not work properly was you were just getting a little jumbled with where to put everything.

**Contents:**

The `MainApp.js` will only contain the `apps` and a method for deleting them in the backend. Other than those two methods, nothing else really concerns the `MainApp.js` file.

The `AppList.js` will contain all the methods that update its own `checked` state, the delete button itself, and a method to clear the `checked` state on delete.

**Processes:**

First, `MainApp.js` will load and remount with a backend api pull and populate its `apps` state. Once it's finished that, it will pass it on to `AppList.js`. From there, `AppList.js` will render that list as a multi-select field onscreen. The user can then select or deselect any of the options. As an option is selected, its index is pushed to the `checked` state and organized in ascending order.

*(ordering the array isn't that necessary, but I figured it would help if you wanted to retool it sometime down the road)*

When one or more option is selected, a `delete` button will appear. When the user clicks the `delete` button, `AppList.js` will call the `delete` function passed to it from `MainApp.js`, then it will clear the current `checked` state.

Comment: thanks jacob! I did a similar approach. Mainly I made checkbox its own component, using AppList to modify the props. For re-usability I'll keep the checkbox its own thing, but your approach definitely works. Will mark as answer